# Angular and node js files

Tags: node.js, angular

I have node js version v6.11.3 and npm version 3.10.10

After i installed angular and created a project with [this](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) instruction.

Also i have an node js file with code:

**getFileList.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
function getFiles(dir){
var fileList = [];

var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
for(var i in files){
    if (!files.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        var name = dir+'/'+files[i];
        if (!fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()){
            fileList.push(name);
        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

Please help me understand, how should i use this code in my project? I need to get file/folder list of a certain directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs'),
var fpath = require('path'),    
filePath = fpath.join(__dirname, 'file name here');
fs.readFile(filePath, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err,data){
if(!err){
     console.log("data received"+data);
     response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
     //response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plaintext'});
      response.write(data);
      response.end();}else{consloe.log(err)}});
```

you can try this for reading file from system in node